# prevent link anchor redirect when touch a video preview on mobile screen

Tags: html, click, touch

I've made a responsive website built on Bootstrap. There is a page containing a list of videos like below

```
<div class='video-preview-container'>
    <a class='full-video-link' href='...'>
        <video src='...'></video>
    </a>
</div>
```

**Whenever I put my finger on any one of these videos and try to scroll it on my cellphone, it immediately redirects.** It is not a good user experience, in other words, it is too "sensitive". What I would like to achieve is like "m.youtube.com", it will redirect when you actual click rather than just touch and scroll.

I have made some progress. It work as expected on Android phones, but on iphone, I can't click the video unless I click on the right bottom corner. It's quite odd.

```
$('div.video-preview-container a').on('click touchend', handlePopdown); 
function handlePopdown(e){
    if(e.type == 'touchend') { 
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    } 
    else if(e.type == "click") {   
      return true;
    } 
}
```

Comment: You have no `href` attribute. Why it redirects? Do you add href attribute later e.g. using JS codes?

Comment: Ops, there is a href I forgot, just add it.